# Highstock Chart with URL in flag text won't open in new window

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart set up with flags marking events. In the `text` attribute of the flag I have an anchor HTML element with the `target` property set to `_blank`, however when I click the link, the page is opened in the current page/tab as opposed to a new page/tab.

Can someone from the Highcharts team confirm if this use case is supported?

An example flag element:

```
{
    x : Date.UTC(2014,0,21),
    title : '3',
    text : '<a href="http://www.alwaysorderdessert.com/2014/01/brussels-sprouts-salad-with-pecorino.html" target="_blank">Brussels Sprouts Salad with Pecorino, Hazelnuts & Honey</a>'
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not opened, becasue html element is parsed to SVG object. You need to catch click event and use `window.open()`

```
 plotOptions: {
            flags: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var url = this.url;
                            window.open(url, '_blank');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7AegD/3/

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.